# not getting to my else in jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

net mvc application and I am trying to do some validation when someone clicks a button. Here is the code.

```
function productVerify() {
var intQty = $("#txtQty").val();
var strItemName = $("#item_Name").val();
var strItemDescription = $("#item_Description").val();
var intItemID = $("#item_ID").val();
var intItemPrice = $("#item_Price").val();
var strImgUrl = $("item_ImgUrl").val();
var intQty = $("#txtQty").val();

if (intQty < 1) {
    alert("You cannot put an item quantity of 0 in your cart");
    return false;
}
else {
    //post into cart
    alert(strItemName + " " + strItemDescription + " " + intItemID + " " + intItemPrice + " " + strImgUrl + " " + intQty + " " + "I got  this far.....! good job")


  }

}
```

this works in jsfiddle but for some reason it does not fully work in my mvc application. it does work on the first if because if I put a 0 in my text box I get the first alert, but nothing happens on the else inside my mvc application. This one part seems so easy, but it is killing me any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)  which will demonstrate _Not Working_?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use MVC Unobtrusive Validation?

Comment: Please post the rest of the page code.  As you indicated, the code as posted works in a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/77rfh1my/  -- with the exception that since you aren't parsing it as an int, a value of `01` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you using a number in your if statement

```
//if !num
if (parseInt(intQty) == NaN) {
 alert("Please enter a number");
 return false;
} else {
 //if < 1
 if (parseInt(intQty) < 1) {
  alert("You cannot put an item quantity of 0 in your cart");
  return false;
 //if >= 1
 } else {
  //do something
 }
}
```

Comment: I commented out all the code except the variables and this alert alert(strItemName + " " + strItemDescription + " " + intItemID + " " + intItemPrice + " " + strImgUrl + " " + intQty + " " + "I got  this far.....! good job"); and it did not work. I tried the parseInt it did not work. but when I put the if statment back in and put 0 or nothing in the qty box the first half of the if statement runs.